# stack and queue strange error

Tags: c++, stack, queue

```
int main()
{
  char ans = YES;
  Stack card;
  int arr[CARD_PER_DECK];
  int catchVar;//to hode values popped off the stack                                                                        
  int size = 0;
  // put shuffled cards into the stack                                                                                      
  inOrder(arr, CARD_PER_DECK, CARD_NUM_RANGE);
  randomize(arr, CARD_PER_DECK);
  // print(arr, CARD_PER_DECK, card);                                                                                       
  for (int i = 0; i < CARD_PER_DECK; i++){
    card.push(arr[i]);
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  //testing popping                                                                                                         
  for (int i = 0; i < CARD_PER_DECK; i++){
    card.pop(arr[i]);
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
void swap(int *a, int*b)
{
  int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
void randomize(int arr[], int n)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (int i = n-1; i>0; i--){
    int j = rand()%(i+1);
    swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
  } 
}
void print(int arr[], int n, Stack card)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < CARD_PER_DECK; i++){
    card.push(arr[i]);
    cout << arr[i] << " " ;
  }
  cout << endl ;
}


//stack.cpp
Stack::Stack()
{//Sets stack to initial empty state                                                                                        
  capacity = 1;
  stackSize = 0;
  stackArray = new int[stackSize];
  top = -1;
}
void Stack::push(int num)
{
  if (stackSize > capacity){
    resize(capacity*2);
  }
  top++;
  stackArray[top] = num;
  stackSize++;
}
void Stack::resize(int newCap)
{
  int* resizeArray = new int[newCap];
  for (int i = 0; i < stackSize; i++)
    resizeArray[i] = stackArray[i];
  capacity = newCap;
  delete[] stackArray;
  stackArray = resizeArray;
}
```

I tried to put randomized number into a stack and pop them out. it can compiled, but when i run it  I got this error:  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'what():  std::bad_alloc 
I am new to this, could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: As a side note: Call `srand(time(NULL));` only once in the `main()` function. Also note: You can use [`std::random_shuffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to do this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: how to fix it?

Comment: A bad alloc is when memory allocations go wrong. It is likely in your `Stack` class, which you havent shown. Also minimize your example to the affected code. Provide the relevant error message.

Comment: Please put the code for push in the question. Also post the code for resize() since it does the work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ could you help me to check again? i put the push and resize function

Comment: @drescherjm: just put it, could you help me take a look?

Comment: @user3923936 What about starting the debugger, step to this line `int* resizeArray = new int[newCap];` and check which value `newCap` actually is? I'd suspect it's a very big number ([remember the rice grains on the chessboard!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem)) :-P ...

Comment: @user3923936 You should define a fixed number of elements to grow your array (BTW a `std::vector<int>` or [`std::queue<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) would do all of this very well already).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: you are right, the newCap turn out really big. what do you mean by grow my array in a fixed number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your `push()` function to grow the array using a fixed number of elements as follows:

```
void Stack::push(int num) {
    static const int grow = 10; // Grow the array for 10 elements a time
    if (stackSize > capacity){
        resize(capacity + grow);
    }
    top++;
    stackArray[top] = num;
    stackSize++;
}
```